# Blazor WASM Project trying to embed PowerBI Report getting PlatformNotSupportedException error

Tags: powerbi, blazor, embed, webassembly

I have Blazor .NET6.0 WASM Project and am trying to embed a Power BI report in it.

I tried using the below example provided for Blazor Server project
[Embedding Power BI in Blazor](https://blazorhelpwebsite.com/ViewBlogPost/5).
When I try to authenticate and get the access token I am getting `PlatformNotSupportedException` error.

Has anybody embedded a Power BI report in their Blazor WASM(webassembly) application successfully. Please share the details.

Have tried multiple ways also using Power BI library but end up with `PlatformNotSupportedException` error. I have tried using other framework which works but an not able to do in Webassembly project.

Also looks like there is an issue with embedding PowerBi report in Blazor webassembly as per below
[Power BI Embed appears to be literally impossible to authenticate in a Blazor Webassembly application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66392800/power-bi-embed-appears-to-be-literally-impossible-to-authenticate-in-a-blazor-we)

Any help is appreciated
Thanks

Trying to embed a PowerBI Report in Blazor Webassembly project and getting PlatformNotSupportedException exception.

Comment: Can you please provide a complete error message and stack trace for the PlatformNotSupportedException? It would help if you could link to a minimal repro project on GitHub where we could plug in our own tenant ID and so forth.

Comment: Hi Halter, I place the project on my git.

Comment: https://github.com/deepakarora73/PowerBIEmbedd. Please let me know. Thanks

Comment: What is complete error message and stack trace for the PlatformNotSupportedException? And why is the github repro a single zip file?

Comment: Hi Halter, It is complete project in the zip file, If you can just download the zip and ope the solution.